# Cannot exit Vim even using q!

Tags: netrw, quit

I cannot exit vim even when I type `:q!`. I get the error

```
E37: No write since last change (add ! to override)
E162: No write since last change for buffer...
```

I think the buffer is a NetrwTreeListing readonly.

Comment: I noticed this happens in particular after using the `x:special` command within the netrw directory listing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To solve this nuisance with netrw permanently, I added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
" Per default, netrw leaves unmodified buffers open. This autocommand
" deletes netrw's buffer once it's hidden (using ':q', for example)
autocmd FileType netrw setl bufhidden=delete
```

From [Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar/issues/13#issuecomment-47133890).

Answer (score 10):

This usually happens, if there are **two** or more buffers which are modified and Vim then usually toggles between them and shows the error message. So when `:q!` would abort the **current** buffer, it wouldn't not abort the other modified buffer, so therefore Vim protects you from losing changes and gives this error message.

If you are absolutely sure, you want to abort all modifications to **all** loaded buffers, then simply use `:qa!`

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
:bdelete!
```

or

```
:bd!
```

for short. This stands for "buffer delete" and will close the buffer you have open. (Credit goes to [Emil Asmussen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868056/3524982))

After that, you should be able to do `:q!` as normal.

Comment: Ok, but why is it not letting me quit?